# Spark Scala : how to slice an array in array of array

Tags: scala

for an array of array:

```
val arrarr = Array(Array(0.37,1),Array(145.38,100),Array(149.37,100),Array(149.37,300),Array(119.37,5),Array(144.37,100))
```

For example, if the input value is 149.37, I want to do some sort of indexing to get 300. 149.37 occurs two times in arrarr(Array(149.37,100),Array(149.37,300). I want to return the last value using spark scala.

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: if the value has matched, should we return the max next index value within the array or just want to return the final occurrence of the matched value?

Comment: So if you had `Array(Array(100,149.37),Array(300,77.7))` then I assume you'd want `(1)(0)`, the indices that get you to the `300` value. But what if you had `Array(Array(300,77.7),Array(100,149.37))`? There is no next value. What is the correct result for that?

Comment: Hi Jay, I just want to return the final occurrence of the matched value. Hi jwvh, for 
`Array(Array(300,77.7),Array(100,149.37))`, if input is 100, I am looking 149.37.

Comment: @QuencyYu; What if the input is not 100 but is 149.37?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
val result : Doulbe = arrarr.filter(_(0) == 149.37).last(1)
```

or

```
val result: Option[Double] = arrarr.reverse.find(_ (0) == 149.37).map(_ (1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val index = arrarr.lastIndexWhere(x => x(0) == input)
val result = arrarr(index)(1)
```

Test it [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UT9wjne/0)